# How to call function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function:

```
$scope.PinTicketSearch = function(pinTicket) {

    if (pinTicket != null) {
        ticketService.searchTicket(pinTicket)
            .then(function(response) {
                $location.search({
                    "ticketPin": pinTicket
                });
                $scope.TicketDetail = response;
                $scope.ShowDetailsAboutTicket = true;
            });
    }
}
```

and i have this part of code:

```
 if ($location.search().ticketPin)
 {

 }
```

How can i call this function `$scope.PinTicketSearch` and pass parameters from `$location.search().ticketPin`. I tried with `$scope.PinTicketSearch($location.search().ticketPin)` but i get an error

> PinTicketSearch is not a function

Comment: Not enough info. One thing for sure, `PinTicketSearch` is not in the scope or prototype chain (parent scopes). Post more code/HTML.

Comment: In one case im calling PinTicketSearch on click but now i want to call that function if there is ticketPin

Comment: Is the code `if ($location.searhc.ticketPin){..}` in the same controller as the code `$scope.PinTicketSearch`?

Comment: `ticketPin` is an argument for the `PinTicketSearch` function you're creating. you'd have to `$location.search().PinTicketSearch()`...

Comment: @callmekatootie yes it is

Comment: If it's in the same controller, then make sure `if` block goes **after** `$scope.PinTicketSearch` declaration.

Comment: You see, I told you in the first comment to post more code, then would have figured it out much faster.

Comment: @dfsq can i ask u one more question? :)

Comment: @uzhas you can ask another question using the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @MarcB: err, what? This is not how javascript works :)

Answer (score 0):

You should to use a callback, instead of your if:

```
$scope.PinTicketSearch = function(pinTicket, success) {
    if(pinTicket != null) {
        ticketService.searchTicket(pinTicket)
            .then(function(response) {
                $location.search({
                    "ticketPin": pinTicket
                });
                $scope.TicketDetail = response;
                $scope.ShowDetailsAboutTicket = true;
                success();
            });
    }
}
```

and your "if", will be:

```
$scope.PinTicketSearch(pinTicket, function() {
    // your original "if" body
});
```